# Open page after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, http, post, get, xmlhttprequest

I made a XMLHttpRequest post to a page with params, in this case, {file.nodeRef}. Now, I want to open the same URL but with the post parameters to be able to access them. How can I open the page?

The code of my XMLHttpRequest is the following:

```
    var csrf_token = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken();
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "hdp/ws/my-new-page";

    var params = "file={"+file.nodeRef+"}";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Alfresco-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try to use ajaxjquery?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "hdp/ws/my-new-page",
    beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Alfresco-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            },
    data: "file={"+file.nodeRef+"}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       window.location.href = data.redirect;       
    }
});
```

Comment: and why to use ajax jquery?

Comment: @IvanStefanov you have another solution?

Comment: Anyone have another solution? The window.location lost params from post

Comment: GET or POST not solve my problem... I have another problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450697/access-file-of-the-new-page-after-a-custom-action-alfresco 

But yes, for open page, this code can works.